# django rest framweork test: post request broke authentication in get test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have two test defined using `django-rest-framework` test library:

```
def test_read_site_API(self):
    """
    Read a Site trough API
    """
    self.client.login(email='test@mail.org', password='testing' )
    response = self.client.get('/xos/sites/', format='json')
    parsed = json.loads(response.content)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertEqual(len(parsed), 1)
    self.assertEqual(parsed[0]['login_base'], 'test_')

def test_create_site_API(self):
    """
    Create a Site trough API
    """
    data = {
        'name': "Another Test Site",
        'login_base': "another_test_",
        'location': [10, 20],
        'abbreviated_name': 'test'
    }
    self.client.login(email='test@mail.org', password='testing' )
    response = self.client.post('/xos/sites/', data, format='json')
    print(response.content)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    self.assertEqual(Site.objects.count(), 2)
    self.assertEqual(Site.objects.get(name="Another Test Site").count(), 1)
```

If I run only the first test it is working.
If I run both tests the result is:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_read_site_API (core.tests.SiteTestAPI)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/xos/core/tests.py", line 75, in test_read_site_API
    self.client.login(email='test@mail.org', password='testing' )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 563, in login
    login(request, user)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 102, in login
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 198, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/opt/xos/core/admin.py", line 1908, in cache_credentials
    auth = {'username': request.POST['username'],
KeyError: 'username'
```

Any idea on what can be happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not answering your question but instead of calling `self.client.login` every time, I'm sure you should be able to either pass the logged in user to `post` or override the DRF settings in your tests.

Comment: `self.client.login` can be called also in a `setUp` method, not a big deal. What do you mean with 'override the DRF settings?

Comment: In your tests, you could simple skip the authentication. From memory DRF has a setting for the Authentication used (all allowed, HTTP password, Oauth, etc.). So in your tests, you could override that setting.